# Oracle Alias Query Results

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I want to alias the results of one query, and use said alias in another. As a simple example, something like:

```
(select a from foo) as fooResults;

select b from bar
  where b in fooResults;
```

This syntax doesn't work, clearly. Is there a way to accomplish this with vanilla Oracle SQL? If it requires PL/SQL, what is the syntax? Search results all seem to point to column or table aliases.

EDIT: One driving factor is that I want to be able to use fooResults in several queries later, if possible.

Comment: Did you try moving the `fooResults` query to your second one in the where clause? `select b from bar where b in (select a from foo)`

Comment: I considered it, but I don't want it as a part of the same query. Ideally, I'll be able to reference the aliased query from multiple other queries without having to rewrite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options.  The cleanest, assuming you want to retain the alias, is probably to use the `WITH` clause

```
WITH fooResults
  AS( SELECT a
        FROM foo )
SELECT b
  FROM bar
 WHERE b IN (SELECT a
               FROM fooResults)
```

If you want to use the expression in multiple queries, you would realistically want to define `fooResults` as a view.

Whether `fooResults` is a view, an inline view, or a subquery defined in a `WITH` clause, though, you'll have to `SELECT` from it in your `IN` clause.  You can't do `WHERE b IN fooResults` no matter how `fooResults` is defined.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Do you have any suggestions that would make fooResults usable to multiple queries, or would I need to define it as a procedure?

Comment: Also, is there a way I'd be able to just say "where b in fooResults," without having to define a mini subquery?